# Unexpected results from chaining push method in assignment of variable

Tags: javascript

This may be very obvious, but I've encountered this a few times when working with Javascript in different settings.

Currently, I'm working on a React app, and I'm adding an object to an array of objects.

This code below works fine:

```
  handleCreate (site) {
    var sites = this.state.sites;
    sites.push(site);
    console.log(sites); // logs an array of objects, as expected
  }
```

This does not:

```
  handleCreate (site) {
    var sites = this.state.sites.push(site);
    console.log(sites); // logs an integer, the number of objects in the array + 1
  }
```

Why don't they work the same way? What is happening in the second set of code?

Thanks!

Comment: check the documentation for the return value of the `push` method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array.

In the second case you are assigning that returned length to a variable and then logging that variable.

In the first case you are doing nothing with the return value (not assigning the result of the call to push to any variable) and then you are logging the array.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.push()` returns the new length of the array ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value)).

When you do `var sites = this.state.sites.push(site);` you are assigning the length of sites to sites. Its value is an integer from that point on.